# How do I add a property page to CPrintDialogEx

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to implement CPrintDialogEx.  I have some additional needed options and I want to add another property page to the window.  There are no MFC examples and trying the Win API example fails miserably.  It cashes.  What am I doing wrong?

```
CPrintDialogEx dlg;
PROPSHEETPAGE optionsPage1;
HPROPSHEETPAGE hOptionsPage;
memset(&optionsPage1, 0, sizeof(PROPSHEETPAGE));
optionsPage1.dwSize = sizeof(PROPSHEETPAGE);
optionsPage1.dwFlags = PSP_DLGINDIRECT;
optionsPage1.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
optionsPage1.pszTemplate = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_QREPORT_OPTIONS);
optionsPage1.pResource = (DLGTEMPLATE*)IDD_QREPORT_OPTIONS;
optionsPage1.hIcon = NULL;
optionsPage1.pszIcon = NULL;
optionsPage1.pszTitle = "Options";
optionsPage1.pfnDlgProc = AfxWndProc; 
optionsPage1.lParam = NULL;
dlg.m_pdex.nPropertyPages = 1;
hOptionsPage = CreatePropertySheetPage(&optionsPage1);
dlg.m_pdex.lphPropertyPages = &hOptionsPage;
if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
```

NULL pointer crash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> optionsPage1.dwFlags = PSP_DLGINDIRECT;
> ...
> optionsPage1.pResource = (DLGTEMPLATE*)IDD_QREPORT_OPTIONS;
> ```

`IDD_QREPORT_OPTIONS` is an integer, it should not be forced to cast in to `DLGTEMPLATE*`. Doing so will point `pResource` to some random memory address and is likely the cause of crash.

You don't need `pResource` anyway. Replace `PSP_DLGINDIRECT` with `PSP_DEFAULT`, this will instruct `CreatePropertySheetPage` to use `pszTemplate`.

---

[`PROPSHEETPAGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bb774548) documentation:

> `pszTemplate`
>
> Type: `LPCSTR`
>
> Dialog box template to use to create the page. This member can specify
>   either the resource identifier of the template or the address of a
>   string that specifies the name of the template. If the `PSP_DLGINDIRECT`
>   flag in the `dwFlags` member is set, `pszTemplate` is ignored. This member
>   is declared as a union with `pResource`.

Example:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK dlgproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if(LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON1)
            MessageBox(hwnd, _T("test"), 0, 0);
        return 0;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

PROPSHEETPAGE optionsPage1 = { 0 };
optionsPage1.dwSize = sizeof(PROPSHEETPAGE);
optionsPage1.dwFlags = PSP_DEFAULT | PSP_USETITLE;
optionsPage1.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
optionsPage1.pszTemplate = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_QREPORT_OPTIONS);
optionsPage1.pszTitle = _T("Options");
optionsPage1.pfnDlgProc = dlgproc;// AfxWndProc;
```